# How do I update the table(MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

the system throw a error "You can't specify target table 'screening' for update in FROM clause"
How do I completed the update like this?

```
 UPDATE screening
  SET maileddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mailed_date[$screeningId]))
  WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users
  INNER JOIN screening ON
  (users.id = screening.users_id
  AND screening.id = {$screeningId}))
  AND date BETWEEN 05-15/2011 AND 11-15-2011
  LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to remove the LIMIT option (similar to a TOP query in other SQL languages). You are basically saying find me the first 2 items and UPDATE. This may produce unexpected results on tables due to sort order.

Comment: I am sorry. I mistaken it. The error message the system throw is that" You can't specify target table 'screening' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: No, the problem is that OP is selecting from the same that that he's trying to update. It's like trying to replace rotten board on a bridge while standing on the same board.

Comment: I have no issue updating the same table in SQL Server from a subquery. Cannot vouch for MySQL though as it might not allow dirty reads)

Comment: Correct answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394194/how-to-handle-mysql-query-update-like-this/7394362#7394362)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the LIMIT clause in your SELECT subquery.

Comment: I am sorry. I mistaken it. The error message the system throw is that" You can't specify target table 'screening' for update in FROM clause"