# how to handle MYSQL query update like this

Tags: mysql

the system throw a error "You can't specify target table 'screening' for update in FROM clause" How do I completed the update like this?

```
UPDATE screening
SET maileddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mailed_date[$screeningId]))
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users
INNER JOIN screening ON
(users.id = screening.users_id
AND screening.id = {$screeningId}))
AND date BETWEEN 05-15/2011 AND 11-15-2011
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update the table(MYSQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393896/how-do-i-update-the-tablemysql)

Answer (score 1):

You get that error, because you are trying to update the `screening` table and at the same time getting the ids from that same table (joined with `users`). The workaround to this, is to use a subquery, as such:

```
UPDATE screening
   SET maileddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mailed_date[$screeningId]))
 WHERE user_id IN (  
                    select s.id
                      from (

                        SELECT users.id
                          FROM users
                         INNER JOIN screening ON 
                                        users.id = screening.users_id
                                AND screening.id = {$screeningId}
                    ) as s)
   AND date BETWEEN 05-15/2011 AND 11-15-2011
LIMIT 2
```

I only changed the indentation and added the subquery in lowercase.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The system throw the error:Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: I have edited my answer. Changed `select id` to `select s.id`

Comment: I don't know why, but i still get the error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Now I got it. I think the problem was in the `SELECT id` that I changed to `SELECT users.id`. It makes sense, because `users` and `screening` tables both have an `id` column

Answer (score 0):

I think giving alias to screening in the inner query may solve the problem. e.g

```
UPDATE screening
SET maileddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mailed_date[$screeningId]))
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users
INNER JOIN screening s ON
(users.id = s.users_id
AND s.id = {$screeningId}))
AND date BETWEEN 05-15/2011 AND 11-15-2011
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The system throw the error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous. Can you help me to take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can set several tables in the table_definition part of the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE screening,users
SET screening.maileddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($mailed_date[$screeningId]))
WHERE
    users.id = screening.users_id
AND
    date BETWEEN 05-15/2011 AND 11-15-2011
LIMIT 2
```

Take a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html